# matplotlib: how to draw curves with different x and y in one graphic?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I now have three things that I want to plot with matplotlib: the Leistung(blue curve), the meanL(red curve) and the rolmean(yellow curve). The Leistung and the meanL have the same x axis (contains 40200 points), while the rolmean has a different x axis (contains 8000 points). The following is what I have now:
[image]

What I want to do is to use the upper side of the figure frame as the x axis for rolmean. Is there any way to do that?

Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib as plt

fig,ax1=plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(Leistung)
ax1.set_xlabel('Messzeiten [s]')
ax1.set_ylabel(r'Leistung $P_1 + P_2 + P_3$ [W]')
ax1.plot(meanL,'r')
ax2=ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(tmc,rolmean,'orange')

plt.tick_params(direction="in")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You have already used `twinx()`, why not use `twiny()` as well?

Comment: yeah I thought about it too but how can I just use them at the same time? like ax2=ax1.twinx().twiny() or something...?